# embedded Linux: date of system after boot: which file (it's date exaclty) is responsible

Tags: boot, time

Do have an embedded linux device.It has a r/o rootfs. It has no connection to ethernet to get a time from some server. I am used that such a device comes up with date: 1.1.1970.
Here it is different. It seems to get the time from either a date stamp of a file or the file system itself. It seems to be the date of creating the image of rootfilesystem.
I can imagine that only one file (or better it's date) is responsible for that. It is not /sbin/init ... but which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the filesystem type used, the date might come from the metadata of the root filesystem, and not from any particular file.

For example, the `ext2/3/4` filesystem types have the following time information embedded in the filesystem metadata, viewable with the `tune2fs -l` command:

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sda2
tune2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
[...]
Filesystem created:       Sun Jan 17 19:56:31 2021
Last mount time:          Wed May 12 18:27:00 2021
Last write time:          Wed May 12 18:27:35 2021
[...]
Last checked:             Sun Jan 17 19:56:31 2021
```

Other filesystem types may or may not have similar embedded timestamps. On a system that has no persistent real-time clock, the kernel might reasonably take the "last write time" of the root filesystem as a best available guess of the current time, in the hope that the system used to have the correct time when it was running previously.

On a system with a read-only root filesystem, the last write time would - as you already realized - be close to the time of creation (or imaging) of the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, that is very likely the case. I see that date is set after mounting filesystem. I can't check that atm. Need to put this command to device. Can I maybe change that date too?

Comment: Well, if you set the system clock and then mount the filesystem in read+write mode, that should update the "last mount time". If you also write something - anything - to the filesystem, that should also update the "last write time".

Comment: Thanks, you are right - that works.

Comment: From what I see now there is a file /etc/timestamp that contains data of creation of filesystem.  Remove that and your system boots up at 1970/1/1.